# Separte Pandas df into a separate tables

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following table (pandas-data-frame) I want to separate Time, Temp, Weather, ...etc to a separate column.

```
    Conditions
    Comfort
February 1, 2016    [{'Time': '12:58 amMon, Feb 1', 'Temp': '50°F', 'Weather': 'Light rain. Mostly cloudy.', 'Wind': '13 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '88%', 'Visibility': '29.79 "Hg'}, {'Time': '1:58 am', 'Temp': '46°F', 'Weather': 'Mostly cloudy.', 'Wind': '12 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '83%', 'Visibility': '29.82 "Hg'}, {'Time': '2:58 am', 'Temp': '43°F', 'Weather': 'Mostly cloudy.', 'Wind': '14 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '85%', 'Visibility': '29.87 "Hg'}, {'Time': '3:58 am', 'Temp': '42°F', 'Weather': 'Mostly cloudy.', 'Wind': '10 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '83%', 'Visibility': '29.89 "Hg'}, {'Time': '4:58 am', 'Temp': '41°F', 'Weather': 'Mostly cloudy.', 'Wind': '10 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '82%', 'Visibility': '29.91 "Hg'}, {'Time': '5:58 am', 'Temp': '39°F', 'Weather': 'Mostly cloudy.', 'Wind': '8 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '83%', 'Visibility': '29.93 "Hg'}, {'Time': '6:58 am', 'Temp': '38°F', 'Weather': 'Partly cloudy.', 'Wind': '5 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '82%', 'Visibility': '29.96 "Hg'}, {'Time': '7:58 am', 'Temp': '38°F', 'Weather': 'Partly sunny.', 'Wind': '5 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '80%', 'Visibility': '29.99 "Hg'}, {'Time': '8:58 am', 'Temp': '38°F', 'Weather': 'Overcast.', 'Wind': '5 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '78%', 'Visibility': '30.01 "Hg'}, {'Time': '9:58 am', 'Temp': '40°F', 'Weather': 'Broken clouds.', 'Wind': '7 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': 'N/A', 'Visibility': '30.01 "Hg'}, {'Time': '10:58 am', 'Temp': '41°F', 'Weather': 'Broken clouds.', 'Wind': '1 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '72%', 'Visibility': '30.02 "Hg'}, {'Time': '11:58 am', 'Temp': '41°F', 'Weather': 'Partly sunny.', 'Wind': '2 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '70%', 'Visibility': '30.04 "Hg'}, {'Time': '12:58 pm', 'Temp': '42°F', 'Weather': 'Scattered clouds.', 'Wind': '2 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '69%', 'Visibility': '30.04 "Hg'}, {'Time': '1:58 pm', 'Temp': '43°F', 'Weather': 'Partly sunny.', 'Wind': '3 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '65%', 'Visibility': '30.03 "Hg'}, {'Time': '2:58 pm', 'Temp': '44°F', 'Weather': 'Partly sunny.', 'Wind': 'No wind', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '62%', 'Visibility': '30.02 "Hg'}, {'Time': '3:58 pm', 'Temp': '46°F', 'Weather': 'Passing clouds.', 'Wind': '6 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '58%', 'Visibility': '30.03 "Hg'}, {'Time': '4:58 pm', 'Temp': '46°F', 'Weather': 'Sunny.', 'Wind': '6 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '57%', 'Visibility': '30.04 "Hg'}, {'Time': '5:58 pm', 'Temp': '43°F', 'Weather': 'Clear.', 'Wind': '3 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '65%', 'Visibility': '30.06 "Hg'}, {'Time': '6:58 pm', 'Temp': '39°F', 'Weather': 'Clear.', 'Wind': '1 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '71%', 'Visibility': '30.09 "Hg'}, {'Time': '7:58 pm', 'Temp': '35°F', 'Weather': 'Clear.', 'Wind': '1 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '79%', 'Visibility': '30.11 "Hg'}, {'Time': '8:58 pm', 'Temp': '32°F', 'Weather': 'Clear.', 'Wind': 'No wind', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '85%', 'Visibility': '30.13 "Hg'}, {'Time': '9:58 pm', 'Temp': '30°F', 'Weather': 'Clear.', 'Wind': 'No wind', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '91%', 'Visibility': '30.14 "Hg'}, {'Time': '10:58 pm', 'Temp': '28°F', 'Weather': 'Clear.', 'Wind': '5 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '93%', 'Visibility': '30.14 "Hg'}, {'Time': '11:58 pm', 'Temp': '29°F', 'Weather': 'Clear.', 'Wind': 'No wind', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '90%', 'Visibility': '30.13 "Hg'}]
February 10, 2016   [{'Time': '12:58 amWed, Feb 10', 'Temp': '17°F', 'Weather': 'Mostly cloudy.', 'Wind': '13 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '72%', 'Visibility': '29.91 "Hg'}, {'Time': '1:58 am', 'Temp': '15°F', 'Weather': 'Mostly cloudy.', 'Wind': '10 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '72%', 'Visibility': '29.91 "Hg'}, {'Time': '2:58 am', 'Temp': '15°F', 'Weather': 'Mostly cloudy.', 'Wind': '10 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '72%', 'Visibility': '29.92 "Hg'}, {'Time': '4:58 am', 'Temp': '15°F', 'Weather': 'Light snow. Overcast.', 'Wind': '13 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '82%', 'Visibility': '29.93 "Hg'}, {'Time': '5:58 am', 'Temp': '15°F', 'Weather': 'Light snow. Mostly cloudy.', 'Wind': '13 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '83%', 'Visibility': '29.93 "Hg'}, {'Time': '6:58 am', 'Temp': '15°F', 'Weather': 'Light snow. Overcast.', 'Wind': '14 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '82%', 'Visibility': '29.95 "Hg'}, {'Time': '7:58 am', 'Temp': '15°F', 'Weather': 'Light snow. Overcast.', 'Wind': '15 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '79%', 'Visibility': '29.96 "Hg'}, {'Time': '8:58 am', 'Temp': '15°F', 'Weather': 'Light snow. Overcast.', 'Wind': '10 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '81%', 'Visibility': '29.98 "Hg'}, {'Time': '9:58 am', 'Temp': '16°F', 'Weather': 'Light snow. Overcast.', 'Wind': '15 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '77%', 'Visibility': '29.99 "Hg'}, {'Time': '10:58 am', 'Temp': '17°F', 'Weather': 'Light snow. Cloudy.', 'Wind': '15 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '75%', 'Visibility': '30.01 "Hg'}, {'Time': '11:58 am', 'Temp': '17°F', 'Weather': 'Light snow. Overcast.', 'Wind': '14 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '74%', 'Visibility': '30.02 "Hg'}, {'Time': '12:58 pm', 'Temp': '18°F', 'Weather': 'Light snow. Overcast.', 'Wind': '17 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '77%', 'Visibility': '30.01 "Hg'}, {'Time': '1:58 pm', 'Temp': '18°F', 'Weather': 'Overcast.', 'Wind': '15 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '67%', 'Visibility': '30.02 "Hg'}, {'Time': '2:58 pm', 'Temp': '17°F', 'Weather': 'Light snow. Mostly cloudy.', 'Wind': '15 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '69%', 'Visibility': '30.02 "Hg'}, {'Time': '3:58 pm', 'Temp': '16°F', 'Weather': 'Mostly cloudy.', 'Wind': '18 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '67%', 'Visibility': '30.03 "Hg'}, {'Time': '4:58 pm', 'Temp': '16°F', 'Weather': 'Overcast.', 'Wind': '16 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '65%', 'Visibility': '30.06 "Hg'}, {'Time': '5:58 pm', 'Temp': '15°F', 'Weather': 'Light snow. Overcast.', 'Wind': '17 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '71%', 'Visibility': '30.08 "Hg'}, {'Time': '6:58 pm', 'Temp': '14°F', 'Weather': 'Overcast.', 'Wind': '16 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '73%', 'Visibility': '30.11 "Hg'}, {'Time': '7:58 pm', 'Temp': '15°F', 'Weather': 'Overcast.', 'Wind': '12 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '67%', 'Visibility': '30.11 "Hg'}, {'Time': '8:58 pm', 'Temp': '13°F', 'Weather': 'Passing clouds.', 'Wind': '12 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '65%', 'Visibility': '30.14 "Hg'}, {'Time': '9:58 pm', 'Temp': '13°F', 'Weather': 'Passing clouds.', 'Wind': '15 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '64%', 'Visibility': '30.14 "Hg'}, {'Time': '10:58 pm', 'Temp': '13°F', 'Weather': 'Passing clouds.', 'Wind': '12 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '64%', 'Visibility': '30.15 "Hg'}, {'Time': '11:58 pm', 'Temp': '12°F', 'Weather': 'Passing clouds.', 'Wind': '9 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '64%', 'Visibility': '30.15 "Hg'}]
February 11, 2016   [{'Time': '12:58 amThu, Feb 11', 'Temp': '11°F', 'Weather': 'Clear.', 'Wind': '7 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '66%', 'Visibility': '30.16 "Hg'}, {'Time': '1:58 am', 'Temp': '9°F', 'Weather': 'Clear.', 'Wind': '5 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '69%', 'Visibility': '30.16 "Hg'}, {'Time': '2:58 am', 'Temp': '8°F', 'Weather': 'Passing clouds.', 'Wind': '5 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '75%', 'Visibility': '30.17 "Hg'}, {'Time': '3:58 am', 'Temp': '8°F', 'Weather': 'Passing clouds.', 'Wind': '8 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '77%', 'Visibility': '30.19 "Hg'}, {'Time': '4:58 am', 'Temp': '6°F', 'Weather': 'Passing clouds.', 'Wind': '3 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '81%', 'Visibility': '30.20 "Hg'}, {'Time': '5:58 am', 'Temp': '8°F', 'Weather': 'Passing clouds.', 'Wind': '5 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '84%', 'Visibility': '30.22 "Hg'}, {'Time': '6:58 am', 'Temp': '7°F', 'Weather': 'Passing clouds.', 'Wind': '2 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '87%', 'Visibility': '30.25 "Hg'}, {'Time': '7:58 am', 'Temp': '8°F', 'Weather': 'Scattered clouds.', 'Wind': '5 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '87%', 'Visibility': '30.28 "Hg'}, {'Time': '8:58 am', 'Temp': '9°F', 'Weather': 'Partly sunny.', 'Wind': '6 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '83%', 'Visibility': '30.30 "Hg'}, {'Time': '9:58 am', 'Temp': '14°F', 'Weather': 'Overcast.', 'Wind': '3 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '74%', 'Visibility': '30.32 "Hg'}, {'Time': '10:58 am', 'Temp': '18°F', 'Weather': 'Partly sunny.', 'Wind': '9 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '61%', 'Visibility': '30.31 "Hg'}, {'Time': '11:58 am', 'Temp': '20°F', 'Weather': 'Partly sunny.', 'Wind': '10 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '57%', 'Visibility': '30.31 "Hg'}, {'Time': '12:58 pm', 'Temp': '21°F', 'Weather': 'Overcast.', 'Wind': '12 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '48%', 'Visibility': '30.30 "Hg'}, {'Time': '1:58 pm', 'Temp': '22°F', 'Weather': 'Partly sunny.', 'Wind': '7 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '48%', 'Visibility': '30.29 "Hg'}, {'Time': '2:58 pm', 'Temp': '23°F', 'Weather': 'Overcast.', 'Wind': '9 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '47%', 'Visibility': '30.30 "Hg'}, {'Time': '3:58 pm', 'Temp': '22°F', 'Weather': 'Overcast.', 'Wind': '6 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '49%', 'Visibility': '30.31 "Hg'}, {'Time': '4:58 pm', 'Temp': '22°F', 'Weather': 'Overcast.', 'Wind': '8 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '50%', 'Visibility': '30.32 "Hg'}, {'Time': '5:58 pm', 'Temp': '21°F', 'Weather': 'Partly sunny.', 'Wind': '8 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '51%', 'Visibility': '30.33 "Hg'}, {'Time': '6:58 pm', 'Temp': '20°F', 'Weather': 'Overcast.', 'Wind': '3 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '50%', 'Visibility': '30.34 "Hg'}, {'Time': '7:58 pm', 'Temp': '18°F', 'Weather': 'Passing clouds.', 'Wind': 'No wind', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '57%', 'Visibility': '30.36 "Hg'}, {'Time': '8:58 pm', 'Temp': '17°F', 'Weather': 'Passing clouds.', 'Wind': '2 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '64%', 'Visibility': '30.34 "Hg'}, {'Time': '9:58 pm', 'Temp': '14°F', 'Weather': 'Passing clouds.', 'Wind': '2 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '70%', 'Visibility': '30.34 "Hg'}, {'Time': '10:58 pm', 'Temp': '14°F', 'Weather': 'Passing clouds.', 'Wind': 'No wind', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '75%', 'Visibility': '30.33 "Hg'}, {'Time': '11:58 pm', 'Temp': '14°F', 'Weather': 'Clear.', 'Wind': '2 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '71%', 'Visibility': '30.27 "Hg'}]
February 12, 2016   [{'Time': '12:58 amFri, Feb 12', 'Temp': '12°F', 'Weather': 'Clear.', 'Wind': '2 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '73%', 'Visibility': '30.31 "Hg'}, {'Time': '1:58 am', 'Temp': '10°F', 'Weather': 'Clear.', 'Wind': '2 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '78%', 'Visibility': '30.29 "Hg'}, {'Time': '2:58 am', 'Temp': '10°F', 'Weather': 'Clear.', 'Wind': '2 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '80%', 'Visibility': '30.28 "Hg'}, {'Time': '3:58 am', 'Temp': '10°F', 'Weather': 'Clear.', 'Wind': '2 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '78%', 'Visibility': '30.26 "Hg'}, {'Time': '4:58 am', 'Temp': '11°F', 'Weather': 'Mostly cloudy.', 'Wind': '2 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '79%', 'Visibility': '30.24 "Hg'}, {'Time': '5:58 am', 'Temp': '12°F', 'Weather': 'Mostly cloudy.', 'Wind': '3 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '77%', 'Visibility': '30.24 "Hg'}, {'Time': '6:58 am', 'Temp': '14°F', 'Weather': 'Passing clouds.', 'Wind': 'No wind', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '75%', 'Visibility': '30.22 "Hg'}, {'Time': '7:58 am', 'Temp': '13°F', 'Weather': 'Partly sunny.', 'Wind': '3 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '75%', 'Visibility': '30.21 "Hg'}, {'Time': '8:58 am', 'Temp': '16°F', 'Weather': 'Cloudy.', 'Wind': '3 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '68%', 'Visibility': '30.21 "Hg'}, {'Time': '9:58 am', 'Temp': '19°F', 'Weather': 'Overcast.', 'Wind': '2 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '60%', 'Visibility': '30.19 "Hg'}, {'Time': '10:58 am', 'Temp': '23°F', 'Weather': 'Mostly cloudy.', 'Wind': '9 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '55%', 'Visibility': '30.18 "Hg'}, {'Time': '11:58 am', 'Temp': '24°F', 'Weather': 'Overcast.', 'Wind': '13 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '56%', 'Visibility': '30.16 "Hg'}, {'Time': '12:58 pm', 'Temp': '25°F', 'Weather': 'Mostly cloudy.', 'Wind': '14 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '54%', 'Visibility': '30.13 "Hg'}, {'Time': '1:59 pm', 'Temp': '25°F', 'Weather': 'More clouds than sun.', 'Wind': '16 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '54%', 'Visibility': '30.05 "Hg'}, {'Time': '2:58 pm', 'Temp': '26°F', 'Weather': 'Partly sunny.', 'Wind': '18 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '53%', 'Visibility': '30.09 "Hg'}, {'Time': '3:58 pm', 'Temp': '26°F', 'Weather': 'Overcast.', 'Wind': '17 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '56%', 'Visibility': '30.09 "Hg'}, {'Time': '4:58 pm', 'Temp': '26°F', 'Weather': 'Light snow. Broken clouds.', 'Wind': '16 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '66%', 'Visibility': '30.11 "Hg'}, {'Time': '5:56 pm', 'Temp': '25°F', 'Weather': 'Light snow. Partly sunny.', 'Wind': '14 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '74%', 'Visibility': '30.07 "Hg'}, {'Time': '5:58 pm', 'Temp': '24°F', 'Weather': 'Light snow. Partly sunny.', 'Wind': '15 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '80%', 'Visibility': '30.12 "Hg'}, {'Time': '6:58 pm', 'Temp': '22°F', 'Weather': 'Light snow. Partly cloudy.', 'Wind': '22 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '74%', 'Visibility': '30.16 "Hg'}, {'Time': '7:58 pm', 'Temp': '21°F', 'Weather': 'Light snow. Passing clouds.', 'Wind': '15 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '63%', 'Visibility': '30.21 "Hg'}, {'Time': '8:58 pm', 'Temp': '20°F', 'Weather': 'Passing clouds.', 'Wind': '14 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '57%', 'Visibility': '30.23 "Hg'}, {'Time': '9:58 pm', 'Temp': '18°F', 'Weather': 'Passing clouds.', 'Wind': '14 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '58%', 'Visibility': '30.26 "Hg'}, {'Time': '10:58 pm', 'Temp': '17°F', 'Weather': 'Clear.', 'Wind': '13 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '65%', 'Visibility': '30.28 "Hg'}, {'Time': '11:58 pm', 'Temp': '16°F', 'Weather': 'Passing clouds.', 'Wind': '16 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '62%', 'Visibility': '30.31 "Hg'}]
```

So, one day row values (i.e Feb 1) is:

```
February 1, 2016    [{'Time': '12:58 amMon, Feb 1', 'Temp': '50°F', 'Weather': 'Light rain. Mostly cloudy.', 'Wind': '13 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '88%', 'Visibility': '29.79 "Hg'}, {'Time': '1:58 am', 'Temp': '46°F', 'Weather': 'Mostly cloudy.', 'Wind': '12 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '83%', 'Visibility': '29.82 "Hg'}, {'Time': '2:58 am', 'Temp': '43°F', 'Weather': 'Mostly cloudy.', 'Wind': '14 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '85%', 'Visibility': '29.87 "Hg'}, {'Time': '3:58 am', 'Temp': '42°F', 'Weather': 'Mostly cloudy.', 'Wind': '10 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '83%', 'Visibility': '29.89 "Hg'}, {'Time': '4:58 am', 'Temp': '41°F', 'Weather': 'Mostly cloudy.', 'Wind': '10 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '82%', 'Visibility': '29.91 "Hg'}, {'Time': '5:58 am', 'Temp': '39°F', 'Weather': 'Mostly cloudy.', 'Wind': '8 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '83%', 'Visibility': '29.93 "Hg'}, {'Time': '6:58 am', 'Temp': '38°F', 'Weather': 'Partly cloudy.', 'Wind': '5 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '82%', 'Visibility': '29.96 "Hg'}, {'Time': '7:58 am', 'Temp': '38°F', 'Weather': 'Partly sunny.', 'Wind': '5 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '80%', 'Visibility': '29.99 "Hg'}, {'Time': '8:58 am', 'Temp': '38°F', 'Weather': 'Overcast.', 'Wind': '5 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '78%', 'Visibility': '30.01 "Hg'}, {'Time': '9:58 am', 'Temp': '40°F', 'Weather': 'Broken clouds.', 'Wind': '7 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': 'N/A', 'Visibility': '30.01 "Hg'}, {'Time': '10:58 am', 'Temp': '41°F', 'Weather': 'Broken clouds.', 'Wind': '1 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '72%', 'Visibility': '30.02 "Hg'}, {'Time': '11:58 am', 'Temp': '41°F', 'Weather': 'Partly sunny.', 'Wind': '2 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '70%', 'Visibility': '30.04 "Hg'}, {'Time': '12:58 pm', 'Temp': '42°F', 'Weather': 'Scattered clouds.', 'Wind': '2 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '69%', 'Visibility': '30.04 "Hg'}, {'Time': '1:58 pm', 'Temp': '43°F', 'Weather': 'Partly sunny.', 'Wind': '3 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '65%', 'Visibility': '30.03 "Hg'}, {'Time': '2:58 pm', 'Temp': '44°F', 'Weather': 'Partly sunny.', 'Wind': 'No wind', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '62%', 'Visibility': '30.02 "Hg'}, {'Time': '3:58 pm', 'Temp': '46°F', 'Weather': 'Passing clouds.', 'Wind': '6 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '58%', 'Visibility': '30.03 "Hg'}, {'Time': '4:58 pm', 'Temp': '46°F', 'Weather': 'Sunny.', 'Wind': '6 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '57%', 'Visibility': '30.04 "Hg'}, {'Time': '5:58 pm', 'Temp': '43°F', 'Weather': 'Clear.', 'Wind': '3 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '65%', 'Visibility': '30.06 "Hg'}, {'Time': '6:58 pm', 'Temp': '39°F', 'Weather': 'Clear.', 'Wind': '1 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '71%', 'Visibility': '30.09 "Hg'}, {'Time': '7:58 pm', 'Temp': '35°F', 'Weather': 'Clear.', 'Wind': '1 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '79%', 'Visibility': '30.11 "Hg'}, {'Time': '8:58 pm', 'Temp': '32°F', 'Weather': 'Clear.', 'Wind': 'No wind', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '85%', 'Visibility': '30.13 "Hg'}, {'Time': '9:58 pm', 'Temp': '30°F', 'Weather': 'Clear.', 'Wind': 'No wind', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '91%', 'Visibility': '30.14 "Hg'}, {'Time': '10:58 pm', 'Temp': '28°F', 'Weather': 'Clear.', 'Wind': '5 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '93%', 'Visibility': '30.14 "Hg'}, {'Time': '11:58 pm', 'Temp': '29°F', 'Weather': 'Clear.', 'Wind': 'No wind', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '90%', 'Visibility': '30.13 "Hg'}]
```

The final desired result looks like as shown below (for each day of month):

```
 barometer    humidity  temp     time    visibility weather  wind
0   30.00 "Hg   76%     36 °F   12:58 am    10 mi   Clear.  No wind
1   30.00 "Hg   80%     35 °F   1:58 am     10 mi   Clear.  2 mph
2   29.97 "Hg   79%     35 °F   2:58 am     10 mi   Clear.  2 mph
3   29.95 "Hg   88%     31 °F   3:58 am     10 mi   Clear.  3 mph
4   29.94 "Hg   90%     30 °F   4:58 am     10 mi   Clear.  3 mph
5   29.95 "Hg   92%     30 °F   5:58 am     10 mi   Clear.  2 mph
6   29.93 "Hg   86%     31 °F   6:58 am     10 mi   Clear.  2 mph
7   29.92 "Hg   94%     33 °F   7:58 am     10 mi   Sunny.  1 mph
8   29.88 "Hg   71%     42 °F   8:58 am     10 mi   Sunny.  6 mph
9   29.82 "Hg   61%     47 °F   9:58 am     10 mi   Sunny.  7 mph
10  29.79 "Hg   48%     52 °F   10:58 am    10 mi   P.sunny. 8 mph
```

I will appricate a short code.

**Note:** there is arrows like this '↑' after "Humidity",it can be added into a separate colomn , to be called (wind direction).

here is how it looks in Jupyter note book:
[image]

Comment: Can you provide minimal table example please?

Comment: @Lev Zakharov I updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you have a `Series` with lists of dicts that describe some day info. This `Series` is second column of your table. I use only few rows for simplicity:

```
data = pd.Series([
[{'Time': '12:58 amMon, Feb 1', 'Temp': '50°F', 'Weather': 'Light rain. Mostly cloudy.', 'Wind': '13 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '88%', 'Visibility': '29.79 "Hg'},{'Time': '1:58 am', 'Temp': '46°F', 'Weather': 'Mostly cloudy.', 'Wind': '12 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '83%', 'Visibility': '29.82 "Hg'}],
[{'Time': '12:58 amWed, Feb 10', 'Temp': '17°F', 'Weather': 'Mostly cloudy.', 'Wind': '13 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '72%', 'Visibility': '29.91 "Hg'}, {'Time': '1:58 am', 'Temp': '15°F', 'Weather': 'Mostly cloudy.', 'Wind': '10 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '72%', 'Visibility': '29.91 "Hg'}]])
```

It looks like:

```
0    [{'Time': '12:58 amMon, Feb 1', 'Temp': '50°F'...
1    [{'Time': '12:58 amWed, Feb 10', 'Temp': '17°F...
```

Now, I want to flatten this `Series` of lists of dicts to just `Series` of dicts:

```
from itertools import chain

flatten = list(chain.from_iterable(data))
```

And then construct resulting data frame:

```
result = pd.DataFrame(flatten)
```

Which looks like:

```
  Barometer Humidity  Temp   ...   Visibility                     Weather    Wind
0       88%        ↑  50°F   ...    29.79 "Hg  Light rain. Mostly cloudy.  13 mph
1       83%        ↑  46°F   ...    29.82 "Hg              Mostly cloudy.  12 mph
2       72%        ↑  17°F   ...    29.91 "Hg              Mostly cloudy.  13 mph
3       72%        ↑  15°F   ...    29.91 "Hg              Mostly cloudy.  10 mph

[4 rows x 7 columns]
```

Do the same actions on your full dataset and be happy!

Comment: Dear@Lev Zakharov, do you mean I have to write {'Time': '12:58 amMon, Feb 1', 'Temp': '50°F', 'Weather': 'Light rain. Mostly cloudy.', 'Wind': '13 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '88%', 'Visibility': '29.79 "Hg'} as one series?

Comment: so it will be pd.Series(['Time': '12:58 amMon, Feb 1', 'Temp': '50°F', 'Weather': 'Light rain. Mostly cloudy.', 'Wind': '13 mph', 'Humidity': '↑', 'Barometer': '88%', 'Visibility': '29.79 "Hg'], am I right?

Comment: @KingJulien, you don't need to write it by yourself. Just select the second column of your table.

Comment: actually, I want to do this for a large dataset it includes many years, I will appreciate if you can provide me a for loop to do that, I am a beginner in creating loops. Thanks

Comment: I also have the  '↑' after "Humidity" I need to take it out to be a separate column

Comment: First, select your column with lists from you data frame. Then make it flatten. This new `Series` will contain dicts for each day as separate elements. Then create data frame from this series. And only after edit your new table as you need (change "Humidity" and add new column for the wind).

Comment: I will be very grateful if you can show me how to do it, by modifying your answer to look like the desired table, thank you so much for your time.

Comment: this is what I did following your instructions: data =  pd.Series(df.iloc[4, :].values) for selecting 4 rows. Is it correct?

Comment: I am getting an error when I run the flatten line: NameError: name 'chain' is not defined

Comment: Sure, you need to import it from `itertools`. Fixed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177763/discussion-between-lev-zakharov-and-king-julien).